# How have multiple user with django admin and mongodb?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-admin

I'm using django admin with mongodb. At the begining all worked perfectly, I could access to django admin with my superuser account but after I tried to create an another user with is_staff = true I had this error when I tried to connect with this account:

> DatabaseError: This query is not supported by the database.

Do you have any idea ?

this is a part of my settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'suit',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'debug_toolbar', 
'debug_toolbar_mongo',
'djangotoolbox',
'simplepage',)

DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'myDataBase'
   }
}
```

And this is in my mongodb data base :

```
> db.auth_user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ea129c3dccf321ef1c809d"), "username" : "superuser", "first_name" : "", "last_name" : "", "is_active" : true, "email" : "", "is_superuser" : true, "is_staff" : true, "last_login" : ISODate("2015-09-05T00:35:58.962Z"), "password" : "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$05hKhDZvNoNa$hr8/4+M+QdQVEkJd64YN8P5JQOf8Zpap04hABs0Styw=", "date_joined" : ISODate("2015-09-04T21:52:28.338Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55ea37a93dccf32fd9f28a26"), "username" : "user", "first_name" : "", "last_name" : "", "is_active" : true, "email" : "", "is_superuser" : false, "is_staff" : true, "last_login" : ISODate("2015-09-05T00:36:14.590Z"), "password" : "pbkdf2_sha256$10000$Ms6gQc6ya4Qh$o2SUxIc0g0KVxH2aRLWAwvrDE/MDIQTGRRG3Kglst0s=", "date_joined" : ISODate("2015-09-05T00:30:32.968Z") }
```

Comment: Try `./manage.py createsuperuser somename` to make a new `superuser`.

Comment: Yes I can create new superuser but when I try to pass is_superuser to False and keep is_staff to True I get the same error. Cause I'd like have a user with read only permission.